# Rails, How to determine if a Nested Record Set Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following two models:

```
Project, has_many ProjectParticipants
ProjectParticipants, belongs_to Project
```

How can I request to determine given these 5 ProjectParticipants, do they belong to a Project?

Also, it should be strictly those 5, not more or less.

Any thoughts on how to elegantly solve for this type of count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `participants` contain the 5 participants you want to check.

```
participants.all? {|o| o.project }
```

This will return true of all participants have a project, otherwise false.

To return the project that was found you can do:

And to see if all participants have the same project:

```
first_participant = participants.shift

participants.all? {|o| o.project == first_participant.project} unless first_participant.nil?
```

The good thing about this method is that it short circuits if one of the participant's doesn't have the same project(more efficient).

Edit:

To return the project that they all share, you can do:

```
first_participant = participants.shift

project_shared = participants.all? {|o| o.project == first_participant.project} and first_particpant.project unless first_participant.nil?
```

project_shared will be set to the project that they are all share, otherwise it will be to nil/false.

So you can then do:

```
if project_shared
  # do work
else
 # they dont share a project!
end
```

Comment: Mike that's the issue, I don't have a project. Given the participants, I want to determine does a project exists for these people or not?

Comment: that's that's great. If there does happen to be a match found, is there a way to return that project?

Comment: Thanks for this Mike, I just tried it out and get NoMethodError (undefined method `project.' for #<User:0x10fa4de30>):

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the properties of the ProjectParticipant records in a group:

```
participants.length == 5 and participants.all? { |p| p.project_id == project.id }
```

This validates that your array of participants contains five entries and that all of them have the same project_id assigned. Comparing `p.project == project` will have the side-effect of loading the same Project five times.

To check if they simply belong to a project, you can do this:

```
participants.length == 5 and participants.all? { |p| p.project_id? }
```

That project may be deleted and the reference could be invalid, so you may need to resort to actually fetching it:

```
participants.length == 5 and participants.all? { |p| p.project }
```

You can also use the `group_by` method to see if there's only one project involved:

```
grouped = participants.group_by(&:project)
!grouped[nil] and grouped.length == 1 and grouped.first[1].length == 5
```

The `group_by` method will organize the given array into a hash where the key is specified as a parameter and the value is a list of objects matching. It can be handy for situations like this.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure this will work. Given 5 people, and not knowing anything about the project. I want to determine if those 5 people already belong to an existing project in the db. Thoughts?

Comment: I've added an update. Your question wasn't very clear on the details.